# How do i use Xampp with Laravel outside the htdocs

Tags: php, xampp, laravel-7

I am quite New to `Laravel` so I mistakenly used composers and did my project folder outside of htdocs of `Xampp`.....This is the project name and the location of the project `C:\Users\hamza\seven` and here is the htdocs location `C:\xampp3\htdocs`. i did my `php artisan serve` command to check for the layout of the page but when it came to migration commands im facing this barrier.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create different vhosts for your sites then you can use different urls and locations.

https://www.rechnerhaus.de/blog/mehrere-virtual-hosts-mit-xampp-in-windows-7-ermoeglichen

It's german but i think the examples are good. Otherwise you can take a look at MAMP with the GUI you can create vhosts and set the path and many more. It's easy.

And the last thing is you can run it directly without XAMPP. Go to your folder and run it with artisan something like this `php artisan serve`.